# What data transfer rates should I realistically expect to see with my current setup?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

I plan on upgrading modems soon, but currently I'm running with the following modem and ISP package:

- Motorola SBG900 Docsis 2.0 802.11g
- Cox Premier 50Mbps

Using any test servers I've found so far, any time of day, I'm unable to hit even 5Mbps transfer rates, usually closer to 3Mbps.

Realistically, I understand a couple of things here. First off, I know that 802.11g transfer rates of 54Mbps are theoretical and not a guarantee. Secondly, I'm sure the ISP is providing less than 50Mbps, even with equipment which could handle it. However, I still think I should be seeing higher data transfer rates than this.

Update: Per suggestions below, I tested when wired to the modem and received 15Mbps. Is 15 mbps down to 5mbps a typical drop when going from LAN to wireless?

Comment: why not rule out that its the wifi by connecting over fast or gigabit ethernet?

Comment: Have you tried bypassing wireless and testing the connection speed with a direct ethernet connection to the internet device?  And have you checked what Cox is "promising".  Usually all they say is "up to XXMbps".  .005Mbps meets that spec.

Comment: @Journeyman, I'm trying a direct connection now.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, they say no less than 30Mbps, but their "out" is, "that's with a docsis 3.0 modem.

Comment: Can you explain *precisely* how you are measuring speeds? Are you using some specific speed testing service? If so, what service and *precisely* what is it reporting?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I'm using two http data transfer test applications, one from cox and the other provided by speedtest.net. Both report approximately the same download and upload speeds, ~3Mbps and ~1Mbps, respectively.

Comment: On my home network I typically get about 16Mbps over 802.11g wireless, maybe a bit more, but not more than 20 Mbps. So your situation isn't typical. Also, DOCSIS 2.0 maximum usable speed is (per Wikipedia) 38 Mbps, meaning that even if your Wi-Fi were working properly, it would still bottleneck your connection (assuming the ISP is providing close to the rated speed).

Comment: Dropping from 15Mbps to 5Mbps using 802.11g is not typical. I would carefully look over the wireless configuration, particularly the channel.

Answer (score 1):

[I think everyone may have covered this in the comments, but here goes...]

First, DOCSIS 2.0 maxes out at about 38mbps downstream, so you're paying for better service than your modem can handle.

Second, the fastest anyone can ever get out of 802.11g in perfect conditions and with vendor-proprietary frame-bursting tricks is barely 30mbps of TCP-over-IPv4 throughput. 23mbps without frame bursting. And in real-world conditions (not great signal strength, not a very clean channel), you should be happy with around 15mbps.

So if you're not seeing around 15mbps, check to see if you're on the cleanest channel (at least try channels 1, 6, and 11), and move closer to the AP so your signal strength is better than -60 dBm RSSI.

Overall, to make use of the 50mbps service you're buying, you need to get a DOCSIS 3.0 modem that can bond 2 or more channels together, but if I were you I'd go for a modem that can handle even more bonded downstream channels for the sake of future-proofing. I think state of the art for a modem-only box is about 8 downstream channels (~300mbps) right now in early 2014.

You also need to get a Wi-Fi solution that's better than 802.11g. Don't get suckered by "150N" boxes; they're not that much better than 802.11g. Go at least for something that's simultaneous dual-band, and supports at least 2x2 (2 spatial stream, so 300mbps assuming 40MHz-wide channels) in each band. These may be sold as "300+300 N" or "N600". But even that is still just 2007 technology. Consider spending $199 for something that does 802.11ac.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, aside from clicking through 11 different channels, there doesn't seem to be too much I can do to configure the modem. I've also tried the speed test on several different devices, with only one connected at a time, and received similar results. Because I'm in the same room, I'm guessing there's some problem with the modem. Thanks again.

Comment: @dsell002, What is the difference in throughput in your wired vs wireless test? Was there any difference?   If not, the most likely fix is working with the provider

Comment: @MikePennington, I'd added the wired vs wireless test results as an edit, but somehow they were edited out. They were 15 vs 5 on my latest test. So, even though the data rates aren't what they should be from the ISP, there's still a big drop occurring in the wireless transfer.

Comment: @dsell002 Someone thought your edit was vandalism because you didn't link your two accounts, so your dsell002 account doesn't show up as the owner of this question now that it's on SuperUser. As for trying different channels, just try 1, 6, and 11, and consider using a tool like inSSIDer to help you see what other Wi-Fi networks are around. Also, check your client's signal strength (RSSI). Is it better than -60 dBm?